# Error: Validation Failed Oracle Storage Cloud Service container name must be in the format

Tags: oracle, cloud, oracle-soa, oracle-cloud-infrastructure-classic

I am getting the following error when creating a oracle database backup service.

```
Oracle Storage Cloud Service container name must be in the format https|http://<storagedomain>/{version}/<schema name>/<container name> or <storage service name>-<identity domain name>/<container name>. For example, storagesvc999-usoracleaccoutrial00999/backupContainer
Name of an existing Oracle Storage Cloud Service container in the form https|http://<storagedomain>/{version}/<schema name>/<container name> or <storage service name>-<identity domain name>/<container name>. e.g:storagesvc999-usoracleaccoutrial00999/backupContainer; If not already created, you can create the container by selecting the checkbox provided below.
```

But I am not able to create a cloud storage container as it comes blank all the time.Please suggest me what am I doing wrong here.

Please Help.

Answer (score 1):

I've found some on Oracle community https://community.oracle.com/thread/3884126

Try this. Maybe it will help you